# Problems with JavaScript parseInt and WSH

Tags: javascript, wsh

I'm having trouble with a Windows Scripting Host script.

Here is an example of problem input code:

```
WScript.Echo(typeof(parseInt('woot')))
WScript.Echo(parseInt('woot'))
```

The output is:

```
number
1.#QNAN
```

Shouldn't 'woot' be evaluating as a string? How can I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:

[Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Can a mod please close this request?

Answer (score 0):

Anything from parseInt is a number, since even NaN is treated a number by JS.Therefore, you'd need to check the type of 'woot' before you parseInt it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if parseInt return `NaN` (not a number)

```
isNaN(parseInt('woot', 10))
```

typeof return number becouse `NaN` is number in JavaScript

But remember that `isNaN` is litle bit broken [read more#Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Examples)